# Access nested object in QML slot by id (called from c++)

Tags: c++, scope, qml, signals-slots, qt-signals

I used to have this arrangement of a window with one text field in it, updated with data emitted from c++ :

```
Window{
   id: root
   function qmlSlot(a){
      _textField1.text=a;
   }
   TextField{
      id: _textField1
   }
}
```

The binding is like this:

```
QQuickWindow *window=qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(topLevel);
QObject::connect(src,SIGNAL(someSignal(QVariant)),window,SLOT(qmlSlot(QVariant)));
```

Now I added more things (tabs) to the main window and things don't work straightforwardly anymore.

**A**: When I leave `qmlSlot` in the Window scope, it does not see `_textField1`:

```
Window{
   id: root
   function qmlSlot(a){
      _textField1.text=a;
   }
   TabView{
      Tab{
         TextField{
            id: _textField1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which gives me:

```
qrc:/main.qml:32: ReferenceError: _textField1 is not defined
```

**B**: When I move the slot itself to the scope of `_textField1`, I don't know how to bind to it from c++:

```
Window{
   id: root
   TabView{
      Tab{
         function qmlSlot(a){
            _textField1.text=a;
         }
         TextField{
            id: _textField1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

resulting in:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QQuickWindowQmlImpl_QML_21::qmlSlot(QVariant)
```

How can I have `qmlSlot` called from c++ while accessing nested items (`_textField` in this case)? Is it possible to make it such that I don't have to change the binding code when I decide to change the window layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Tab` is in fact a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html), so it means that your TextField is created on demand and in another context. When your `Tab` isn't active there is no `TextField` to access.

You could access your textfield with `tab.item`, but it would only work when the tab is loaded.

You have a deeper problem though, accessing QML objects from c++ is bad practice as that means that your business layer has to be aware of your UI layer. That's not good if you want to refactor your UI. What you should do instead is pull data from c++ in your QML. More explanation here : [Interacting with QML from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c).

In your case, I would create a `QObject` subclass with a property or a signal (is it a state of your object or an event?).

Then use `setContextProperty` to make one of your object instance available to the QML engine.

And in your QML you'd just do (if it's a property):

```
Window{
   id: root
   TabView{
       Tab{
           TextField{
               text: myCppObject.textProperty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is the proper way to create static tabbed interface, then, not via a Loader? I found (presumably old) [TabGroup](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/qml-tabgroup.html). (2) signals are sent from the backend to QML, it is sensors interface which fires the signal when data arrives. I would like to find a better way to do it but property does not seem to cut it really. Unless the property itself notifies QML (whch knows it is being used) of its change, then it would be easy.

Comment: A property can indeed notify QML of its change. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties

Comment: Alright, then I understand the best is to have a c++ class e.g. `DataHolder` holding all the data (via Q_PROPERTY) exposed in the UI, and assign that instance using `view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataHolder", &dataHolderI);` and then just set properties to `root.dataHolder.x` and so on and they will update automagically. And connect signals to update the DataHolder instance from the rest of c++ code. Makes sense, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

I've never used QML before but the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtqml-documents-scope.html) suggest that you need to assign a value to each object's `id` property so that you can refer to it. I think the following should work (but have not tested it).

```
Window{
   id: root
   function qmlSlot(a){
      mytabview.mytab._textField1.text=a;
   }
   TabView{
      id: mytabview
      Tab{
         id: mytab
         TextField{
            id: _textField1
         }
      }
   }
}
```